# Air Conditioner for an Acrobat Plane

Tags: cooling, thermal-conduction, environmental-engineering, air

What kind of Freon air conditioner would work upside down? Or somehow make it cut off and start working again when upright?  I have a small cabin so it can be electrically driven. I know they have an air conditioner for fighter jets but, I need a cheaper aftermarket one, if cheap is possible?

Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/do-jet-fighters-have-air-conditioning-systems

Comment: you could use an accelerometer to shut it down when negative g's ... tho frequent restarts may be worse. I'd have to guess there are compressors and blowers that can take it. Or is it something else that fails, like drainage?

Comment: You might rather post this on the Aviation SE site. Otherwise Peltier type (thermoelectric) coolers should work in any orientation. They do not use Freon.

Comment: @PeteW You could add a simple timer that keeps the compressor shut down for a minute or 2 after a negative G event. That's to prevent the compressor from trying to start while the built up pressure is spinning it backwards.

Comment: I think it might actually work fine. The compressor is always sucking gas on the evaporator side. It's going to push that gas into the condenser. Towards the end of the condenser it will ..condense into a liquid. Now the question is whether gravity in a specific direction is required to get that liquid into the capillary tube. The flow in the tube might be enough to keep the liquid from trickling back the wrong direction when upside down, but I'm not sure. I think it's unlikely that operating in this way for short periods of time would damage the compressor, but again, I've never tried it.